# identify the topological type obtained by gluing sides of the hexagon

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, surfaces, geometric-topology

> Identify the topological type obtained by gluing sides of the hexagon as shown in the picture below

[image: Surface]

Clearly the boundary is encoded by the word $abcb^{-1}a^{-1}c$

I do not understand how the surface is glued together - could you help me, please?

Edit: This answer is a Klein bottle (see answer below)

Similar problem: see [Is this octogon topologically equivalent to the Klein Bottle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744376/is-this-octogon-topologically-equivalent-to-the-klein-bottle)

[image: Surface 2]

Comment: In your second figure, $d$ and $e$ are boundaries. But a Klein bottle has no boundary.

Comment: Is a topological boundary an edge with no direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the Klein bottle:

[image]

By combining arrows $a$ and $b$ into a single red arrow, and arrows $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ into another red arrow, we get the first figure below. Now we must glue the red sides together, and blue sides together, so that the arrows line up.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is a good answer. I just wanted to ask, how do you know that you can glue $a$ and $b$ together? Is it because they come one after another and in the same direction?

Comment: Yes $a$ and $b$ form a single arrow because they meet and are in the same direction.

Comment: OK thanks. So the general method for this problem would be to join together such consecutive arrows, and see how the simplified boundary compares to that of common topological space, such as klein bottle, torus etc?

Comment: Yes I believe so.  You just have to keep the interior intact when you combine arrows, so that you are still gluing a topological disc.

Comment: Thank you. I added another picture to my question which is pretty much exactly the same except it has two extra sides which have no direction. Would this still be a klein bottle?

Comment: You should probably post your edit in a new question, so that more people will see it.

Comment: @ForeverMozart  I just wanted to check something. Would the sides of $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ not be in the opposite direction to $ab$? Thanks