# Is this octogon topologically equivalent to the Klein Bottle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, klein-bottle

**Note:** this is an extension of a previous problem ([identify the topological type obtained by gluing sides of the hexagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744262/identify-the-topological-type-obtained-by-gluing-sides-of-the-hexagon) ) where a hexagon was considered.

---

> Is the space below also a Klein bottle ($d$ and $e$ have no direction)?

[image: Surface 2]

I know that if the black lines, $d$ and $e$, were removed then we would have a Klein bottle as it would reduce to this:

[image: Klein bottle]

But do the black lines stop it from being topologically equivalent to a Klein bottle, and if so, how?

Thank you

Comment: There are edges that are not glued. These will remain edges in the glued object.  So you will not get a torus, sphere, klein bottle, etc.

Comment: That is to say, the diagram you have presented represents a manifold with boundary as opposed to a manifold without boundary. The klein bottle is of the latter form.

Comment: @TonyS.F. What does boundary mean in a topological sense? I thought the Klein bottle was a closed surface

Comment: Yes, the Klein bottle is a closed surface. And the topological type obtained by gluing the octagon in your question is not a closed surface. Therefore it is not a Klein bottle.

Comment: @LeeMosher How do we know the octagon given is not closed?

Comment: Because the edge $e$ is not identified to any other edge. This forces the image of $e$ in the quotient to be on the boundary of the resulting surface-with-boundary. Thus that surface-with-boundary has nonempty boundary. By definition, a closed surface is a compact surface-with-boundary whose boundary is empty.